# Populate divs based on some value of div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a webpage with multiple divs getting created and populated in forloop (wsgi-python). My javascript is changing only first div and not processing further. How to make it happen on all the divs on the webpage?

https://jsbin.com/taximawino/edit?html,output

Comment: Please post the code and relevant HTML.

Comment: You are using your IDs multple times. An ID must be unique.

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly you want to be done here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id` should be unique , so you can use `class` instead if multiple elements need to be select, then use `data-value` attribute instead of `value` attribute, since it's the proper way to add custom attribute and you can access it using **[`data('value')`](https://api.jquery.com/data/)**. Then you can iterate over jQuery selected element using **[`each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/)** and select previous element using **[`prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/)**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // var mb = $('#state').text();
  $('.state').each(function() {
    var mb = $(this).data('value');
    if (mb == 1) {
      $(this).prev().addClass("circleb");
    } else if (mb == 2) {
      $(this).prev().addClass("circlec");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
div.circlea {
  background-color: #d0e4fe;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
div.circleb {
  background-color: #66FF99;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
div.circlec {
  background-color: #FFCCCC;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="demo" class="circlea"></div>
  <div class="state" data-value="1"></div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="demo" class="circlea"></div>
  <div class="state" data-value="2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I get it but what if I change the <div class="state" data-value="X"></div> to <input type="hidden" value="X"> ?

Comment: because if do <input type="hidden" name="state" value="%s" data-value="%s" class="state"> I dont even see the circle.