# populate divs based on value of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

#### html

```
<li title="State - IpAddress">
    <div>
        <div class="inline">
            <div class="circlecolor" class="no-class"></div>  
        </div>
        <div class="inline">
            <div class="state-ip" data-value="%s">
                <span>%s - %s</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a href="#showInfo" class="popover-control">
            <img alt="Help" height="13" src="images/questionmark.png" title="know more about states" width="13" />
        </a>
    </div>
</li>
```

#### javascript

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.state-ip').each(function() {
        var mb=$(this).data('value');
        alert($(this));

        alert(mb); 
        if(mb == "AVAILABLE"){
          alert("Inside if");
         $(".circlecolor").removeClass().addClass("success");

     }
        else if(mb == "ERROR"){
                alert("Inside error");
                $(".circlecolor").removeClass().addClass("error");
        }
        else{
                alert("Inside else");
                $(".circlecolor").removeClass().addClass("impaired");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

#### css

```
div.no-class{
background-color: #808080;
width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
}

 div.success{
background-color: #009933;
width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
}
 div.error{
background-color: #FF3300;
width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
}

div.impaired{
background-color: #FF9900;
width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
}
```

Following [Populate divs based on some value of div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32913683/populate-divs-based-on-some-value-of-div), I added the above html,css and js into my project.Problem is :

I am doing

```
$('circlecolor').removeClass().addClass("XXXX");
```

so even if control goes to all if and else based on ".state-ip" class value and I can see in logs that it is working fine. But adding color to class is based on first if and for all the divs. How can I do something like
    `$(this.circlecolor).removeClass().addClass("XXXX");` ?

So if I have 2 divs on webpage where state-ip values are "AVAILABLE" and "UNSUABLE", then I expect color "GREEN" and "ORANGE" respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(".circlecolor")` will find all elements with the class `circlecolor` irrespective of the context. Hence, you need to find the [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) list item and then use [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to target the element within the context of the current (`this`) element, as below.

```
$('.state-ip').each(function() {
    var mb = $(this).data('value');
    var $circlecolor = $(this).closest("li").find(".circlecolor");

    $circlecolor.removeClass();

    if(mb == "AVAILABLE") {
        alert("Inside if");
        $circlecolor.addClass("success");

    }
    else if(mb == "ERROR") {
        alert("Inside error");
        $circlecolor.addClass("error");
    }
    else {
        alert("Inside else");
        $circlecolor.addClass("impaired");
    }
});
```

And, here is a shorter version of the above:

```
$('.state-ip').each(function() {

    var mb = $(this).data('value');
    var $circlecolor = $(this).closest("li").find(".circlecolor");
    var _class = mb === "AVAILABLE" && "success" || mb === "ERROR" && "error" || "impaired";
    $circlecolor.removeClass().addClass(_class);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jQuery(this).parents()` to target parents div of your data-* selector and then find .circle there;

```
var mb=$(this).data('value'),
parents = $(this).parents(), //you can specify how deep you want to go via DOM, using parents.eq(n) method
circle = parents.find('.circle')
console.log(circle);
alert($(this));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery's `next`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) to achieve what you want:

```
$(this).next('.circlecolor').removeClass().addClass(XXX);
```